# Remove experience from CV/LinkedIn which doesn't show up on search?

Tags: resume, job-search, united-kingdom

I have a 2-year position at a startup listed on my CV and LinkedIn, I gained some valuable experience working there. The startup operated under stealth mode, and so didn't have much of a web presence; I worry that potential employers would dislike or distrust the fact that this company doesn't show up upon search. Additionally, this company is now defunct, the CEO doesn't even list it on his LinkedIn profile anymore.

Is it advisable to keep that experience visible on my CV and LinkedIn when it could possibly cost me an interview?

Comment: Do you have any proof that you worked there, e.g. past payslips, letters, contracts, etc? You could always provide such proof upon request

Comment: Yes, but this question is to address any unmentioned concerns before an interview is extended.

Comment: And you couldn't submit such paperwork with your CV or link to it on LinkedIn (With confidential data that you don't want shown removed)? That would ease any of your concern and as long as you attach a small note with it explaining why you submitted it, it won't raise too many eyebrows

Comment: That didn't occur to me, it seems onerous, but there could be a nice way of doing this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think a gap in work experience would look worse than working at an unknown company. For LinkedIn, it may be fine to exclude it as it isn't an official CV, but I would keep it on your CV if it is recent work experience.

If it were me, I would just keep it on both of them, and explain them upon further request. It likely isn't your fault that the company didn't succeed or become high profile, so I doubt it would be held against you.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely not. You are advertising what you have learnt. There is no need at this point for evidence. It is normal that companies disappear. If you had a two year gap and were lying about it, making up work experience that you don’t have, that is easily found during an interview.